# I have a dataframe table with a ticker column and a date column. I want to calculate the price of the ticker at the corresponding date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

**Here is the table specified as *df*:**

| id | ticker | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PLTR | 2022-01-07 |
| 2 | GME | 2022-01-06 |
| 3 | AMC | 2022-01-06 |
| 4 | GOOD | 2022-01-07 |
| 5 | GRAB | 2022-01-07 |
| 6 | ALL | 2022-01-06 |
| 7 | FOR | 2022-01-06 |

I want to have something like this:

| id | ticker | date | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PLTR | 2022-01-07 | $16.56 |
| 2 | GME | 2022-01-06 | $131.03 |
| 3 | AMC | 2022-01-06 | $22.46 |
| 4 | GOOD | 2022-01-07 | $24.76 |
| 5 | GRAB | 2022-01-07 | $6.81 |
| 6 | ALL | 2022-01-06 | $122.40 |
| 7 | FOR | 2022-01-06 | $21.26 |

I tried **df['Price'] = yf.download(df['ticker'],df['date'])['Close']**
using the yahoo finance tool but received an error:
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'

I also tried the pandas_datareader (imported as web), got the same error:
df.assign(Price=web.DataReader(list(df.ticker('\n')), 'yahoo', list(df.date)))['Close']

Any advice/ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The problem as you have written the code is that ```d[f'ticker]``` and ```df['date]``` produce a pandas series object.  You need to increment through the df on a row by row basis to extract the ticker price for a item on a specific data.

Comment: Can you add some sample data so your question is [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)?

Comment: The dataframe is exactly the first table

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web

tickers = list(df.ticker)

prices = ( web.DataReader(tickers, data_source='yahoo', start=df.date.min().date(), end=df.date.max().date() )['Close']
   .reset_index()
   .melt(id_vars=['Date'])
   .rename(columns={'Symbols':'ticker', 'Date':'date'})
)

prices:
```

|  | date | ticker | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2022-01-06 00:00:00 | PLTR | 16.74 |
| 1 | 2022-01-07 00:00:00 | PLTR | 16.56 |
| 2 | 2022-01-06 00:00:00 | GME | 131.03 |
| 3 | 2022-01-07 00:00:00 | GME | 140.62 |
| 4 | 2022-01-06 00:00:00 | AMC | 22.46 |
| 5 | 2022-01-07 00:00:00 | AMC | 22.99 |
| 6 | 2022-01-06 00:00:00 | GOOD | 25.03 |
| 7 | 2022-01-07 00:00:00 | GOOD | 24.76 |
| 8 | 2022-01-06 00:00:00 | GRAB | 6.65 |
| 9 | 2022-01-07 00:00:00 | GRAB | 6.81 |
| 10 | 2022-01-06 00:00:00 | ALL | 122.4 |
| 11 | 2022-01-07 00:00:00 | ALL | 125.95 |
| 12 | 2022-01-06 00:00:00 | FOR | 21.26 |
| 13 | 2022-01-07 00:00:00 | FOR | 20.19 |

Now merge them:

```
df.merge(prices, on=['ticker','date'], how='left')
```

|  | id | ticker | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | PLTR | 2022-01-07 00:00:00 | 16.56 |
| 1 | 2 | GME | 2022-01-06 00:00:00 | 131.03 |
| 2 | 3 | AMC | 2022-01-06 00:00:00 | 22.46 |
| 3 | 4 | GOOD | 2022-01-07 00:00:00 | 24.76 |
| 4 | 5 | GRAB | 2022-01-07 00:00:00 | 6.81 |
| 5 | 6 | ALL | 2022-01-06 00:00:00 | 122.4 |
| 6 | 7 | FOR | 2022-01-06 00:00:00 | 21.26 |